# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: exception

Simple codes

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://banweb.cityu.edu.hk/");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
}
```

I have 2 desktops (A and B), 2 laptops (A and B), 3 android devices (A, B and C) and 3 android emulators (SDK v2.1, v4.0 and v4.03). When above code is run in desktop A, android emulator v4.0 and v4.0.3, it throws "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated". But the code works fine in other devices and emulators.

Can anyone tell me why the same code shows different results in different machines?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

See this message post: [SSL "Peer Not Authenticated" error with HttpClient 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750413/ssl-peer-not-authenticated-error-with-httpclient-4-1)

I think the issue is related to whether the machine/environment that you are using has access to the system wide root certificates.  If the OS is newer it may recognize ( and verify/trust?) your signed certificate.  However, if the JRE/JDK is not aware of the root CA store then it may not work.

I have a basic app that is working in Netbeans but not after I deploy the JavaFX project.  I have added my root certificate to the keystore but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that one of the machines is behind a proxy and the other is not?

Comment: If behind the proxy, means it may cause by the proxy? For example, my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149109/can-proxy-server-grouping-incoming-network