# Maven command gives peer not authenticated error few times

Tags: maven, peer

I get this "Peer not authenticated" error when giving mvn clean install command. But the strange thing is it happens few times and it works when I restart the system. If there is any issue with the proxy or firewall then the commands should not work everytime. But just restarting the system makes it working. And then if I lock the system and log back in then "Peer not authenticated" error comes back and have to restart the system then.

Any pointers what may be the issue over here ??

Comment: Certificate problem maybe? Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750413/ssl-peer-not-authenticated-error-with-httpclient-4-1) help?

Comment: If this is supposed to be a certificate issue then it should give the error everytime but it doesn't.