# SSL Certificate Error in a JAVA application on Tomcat7 in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, ssl

I have created a JAVA Application and have deployed it on Tomcat7 in an Ubuntu 16.04 System. The application hits a request on an https:// but returns the following error:

java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

I have tried installing the certificate in the JRE used by the system:

tomcat7   3388     1  0 11:07 ?        00:00:11 **/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java**

But i still get the same error.

I have also installed the certificate in the cacerts.jks keystore and have tried using java

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/security/cacerts.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

But I am still getting the error:

```
java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    in.pwc.FormHandler.doPost(FormHandler.java:184)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:131)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLSocketFactory.java:648)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:623)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:115)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:360)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:177)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:77)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:95)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    in.pwc.test.decrypt(test.java:62)
    org.apache.jsp.viewAdmin_jsp._jspService(viewAdmin_jsp.java:193)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    in.pwc.FormHandler.doPost(FormHandler.java:184)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I am assuming that my java and tomcat are using some other certificate store but I am unable to find the same.

How can I go about solving this error?

Update: I do not need my application to be https or using SSL the request its makes is an HTTPS request which has to be a verified one as a requirement of the appliance.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11750463/4762439) from another post:

> If the server's certificate is self-signed, then this is working as
>   designed and you will have to import the server's certificate into
>   your keystore.
>
> Assuming the server certificate is signed by a well-known CA, this is
>   happening because the set of CA certificates available to a modern
>   browser is much larger than the limited set that is shipped with the
>   JDK/JRE.
>
> You must import the proper Root CA into your keystore to validate the
>   certificate. There's a reason you can't get around this with the stock
>   SSL code, and that's to prevent you from writing programs that behave
>   as if they are secure but are not.

This will solve your issue, but if you want only a local solution (**that is not useful on production**), you can find some options on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308774/httpget-with-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: How do I identify what keystore my java application/tomcat 7 is using? In eclipse I can simply specify it in the JVM parameters. How do I do the same in a linux system?

Comment: Your keystore will be in your `JAVA_HOME > JRE> lib > security > cacerts`. You need to check where your JAVA_HOME is configured. Also, you can find more information in [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html).